# Unwanted line breaks when using print when expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm currently using the `Print When Expression` function on my fields and whenever a field is getting excluded because of the print when condition it is leaving a blank space instead of just skipping it and moving on to the next one. Here is a picture showing what is happening:

[image]

So I'm trying to find a way to ignore that line break and keep the entire list uniform.

Here is my `Print When Expression` condition (which may or may not help you in answering my question): `$F{clicks} < 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the Print When expression to the whole band, not to the fields.